# Set Document to PDFview in controller constructor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdfview

I've created a `NSWindow` with a `PDFView` in xib file, I created a controller called MainController, there, I created a ibaction `-(IBAction) openFileAction:(id) sender`, it uses the method

```
-(void) openFile:(NSString *) path{
  NSLog(@"Opening File %@",path);
  PDFDocument *pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
  [pdfView setDocument: pdfDoc]; 
}
```

I linked the open menu item to `openFileAction` and pdf file is shown properly in PDFView after the click.

I'm doing a logic to receive a command line argument

```
-(MainController *) init{
  [super init];
  NSArray *myArgs = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
  NSLog(@"pdf view %@", pdfView);
  if ([myArgs count] >= 2 ){ 
    [self openFile:[myArgs objectAtIndex:1]];
  }

  return self;
}
```

As you can see, I did an override in default constructor and in this context the pdfView is null then the file is not opened after the application/main Window load.

My question is, how can I open a pdf in a PDFView after the application load? Is there any hook to use after UI load?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this when your window opens that your PDFView is in, use the [windowDidLoad](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/windowDidLoad) function in your MainController rather than trying to load it in init.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks slycrel but windowDidLoad is a callback of NSWindowController. I found the solution by myself, the secret is

```
- (void) awakeFromNib{
 //Do something after initialize UI components 
}
```

All the best.